# How to output the top 4 words that appear most often in a string and the number of times they occur

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

how do i determie the words that appear most often in an array and the amount of times it occurs

Comment: `print_r($result);` is already your answer if your question is what you have in the body, and not in the title

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you need

```
arsort($result);
```

to sort the array by the 4 top count, and then with `array_splice` you take off the top 4 els from the $result.

```
var_dump(array_splice($result, 0, 4));
```

Comment: You must use arsort() before else the result will be Array ( [good] => 1 [don't] => 1 [for] => 1 [are] => 1

Comment: And what about if you don't have 4 words!?!?!

Comment: Not in the question, We aren't consulent but try to help to find the way or at lest try doing it. He has to learn, help he to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$words = array("apples", "are", "good", "for", "you", "or", "don't", "you", "like", "apples", "or", "maybe", "you", "like", "oranges", "better", "than", "apples");
$result = array_count_values($words);
arsort($result);
if (count($result)>=4)
    print_r(array_splice($result, 0, 4));
else
    print_r($result);
```

**OR**

```
$words = array("apples", "are", "good", "for", "you", "or", "don't", "you", "like", "apples", "or", "maybe", "you", "like", "oranges", "better", "than", "apples");
        $result = array_count_values($words);
        arsort($result);
    if (count($result)>=4)
        $result=array_splice($result, 0, 4);
    foreach ($result as $k => $v) 
    {

        echo "[$k] => $v. || ";
    }
```

The result of this code will be:

```
Array ( [you] => 3 [apples] => 3 [like] => 2 [or] => 2 )
```

Comment: how would i output this so that it dispplayed in php file like you 3 
apples 3
like 2 each on a new line

Comment: Use  foreach ($result as $k => $v) 
    {

        echo "[$k] => $v. || ";
    }

Answer (score -1):

```
arsort($result);   
$answer = key($result);
for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
 echo $answer[$i];
}
```

Comment: And what about if you don't have 4 words!?!?!

Comment: krsort() is wrong this is you output: Array ( [you] => 3 [than] => 1 [oranges] => 1 [or] => 2 )

Comment: that is @user1821728 want to print the top 4 and I just give an example and he should check the length of $result after array_count_values function